# How to send Zip using sync-request

Tags: node.js

I was trying to send the zip file to endpoint using Sync-request, request is getting hit to server but still getting error from sync-request

`Error: unexpected end of file`

```
var request = require('sync-request');
var fs = require('fs');

uploadData = fs.readFileSync("filepath/file.gz");

var url = "some endpoint url";

let res = request('PUT', url, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: authenticationToken,
    },
    Body: uploadData
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formData method. The latest version lets you upload files. It does not let you stream the file upload though.

```
const {FormData} = require('sync-request');

const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', fs.readFileSync(file_path), file_path);

request('PUT', url, {form: fd});
```

Ref : https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request/issues/63

Comment: Stll getting the same issue

Comment: can you share your consuming service details, how you are reading teh PUT related contents. Is it a open source service / custom one ? if so share teh code snippet

Comment: Yeah i found the issue, that the service which i was calling is not send any response body  for "PUT" call just it is sending status as 200,  Sync-request is expecting the response body for PUT and it was not finding it in response , so it was throwing the error